# How to check whether JavaScript is enabled in client browser using Java code

Tags: java, javascript

can anyone help me in trying to check whether JavaScript is enabled in client browser using Java code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming you're writing a Java web application, one technique that I've used successfully is to have the first page that's accessed—typically a login form—write a session cookie when the page loads. Then have the Java code that the form submits to check for the existence of that cookie.

On the client:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function createCookie(name, value, days) {
    var expires = "";
    if (days) {
      var date = new Date();
      date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
      expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    }
    var cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=" + "/";
    document.cookie = cookie;
  }
  createCookie("JavaScriptEnabledCheck", 1, 0);
</script>
```

On the server:

```
/**
 * Returns <code>true</code> if the session cookie set by the login form
 * is not present.
 * 
 * @param request The HTTP request being processed
 * @return <code>true</code> if JavaScript is disabled, otherwise <code>false</code>
 */
private boolean isJavaScriptDisabled(HttpServletRequest request)
{
  boolean isJavaScriptDisabled = true;
  Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();

  if (cookies != null)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++)
    {
      if ("JavaScriptEnabledCheck".equalsIgnoreCase(cookies[i].getName()))
      {
        isJavaScriptDisabled = false;
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  return isJavaScriptDisabled;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In yourform for you can put code like this:

```
<noscript>
  <input type="hidden" name="JavaScript" value="false" />
</noscript>
```

The parameter should only be submitted if the browser has scripts turned off. In your Java applications you can check it like so:

```
boolean javaScript = request.getParameter("JavaScript") == null;
```

Comment: I like this idea...but is it a cross-browser solution? It seems like something IE6 would love to mess up.

Answer (score 3):

If a form submit is performed, you can put a hidden input in the form and fill out its value with javascript (from OnSubmit) and check that on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

A simple thing would be to do a call back from the page, such as an AJAX call. I don't think there's any other way to determine this, at least not universally.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do this server-side or on the client in an applet?

If a browser does not support javascript (or has it turned off), it's highly unlikely they will have support for Java applets.

Answer (score 0):

If you have PHP support just copy and paste the code below.

```
<noscript> 
  <input type="hidden" name="JavaScript" value="false" /> 
</noscript> 
/*This code is developed by Lankeshwer(nick name only) and can be used as open source by anyone*/
<?PHP
if($_POST['JavaScript']!='false'){
 echo "<run your javascript code here>";} //replace this line with your actual javascript code
else
 echo "<html><head><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=www.kharida.com"></head</html>";
?>
```

wish you a good luck and don't forget to make your code open