# JavaScript is enabled in client browser in django or in python?

Tags: javascript, django, browser, python-2.7, client

I am trying to find a solution to detect if clients brower has javascript enabled or not.
Is there a way to check whether JavaScript is enabled in the client browser, in django if possible or in python?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/768262/139010

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't do this unless trying a second request. There's no way to know this before actually interacting with the browser itself.

The closest I can think of is trying to set a cookie and store this information for future visits.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The right approach is to degrade gracefully, but that is not always possible especially with web app.  Use a `<noscript>` tag to tell the user to re-enable javascript.

If you need a solution through django, set a cookie using JS and try to read it in the second request. If you dont see the cookie then JS is not enabled.  However, as a first request it can't be detected.